# What is the equivalent of the Java expression "Class.class" in Oxygene?

Tags: java, oxygene

In some Java source for Android I see expressions involving a "class" member on Class types, for example when constructing a ComponentName object:

```
cname := new ComponentName( this, SomeClass.class );
```

This does not compile in Oxygene for Java, with the compiler claiming that there is no such static member 'class' on the type.

What is the equivalent Oxygene syntax ?

Comment: Among other things, yes.  *typeof()* is the answer.

I put this up as a self answered question in case someone else comes along looking for some help with the same thing on SO, just as I did.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "class" member of a Class type in Java is not part of the Java object model but is interpreted directly by the Java compiler.  What is sometimes called "compiler magic".

The equivalent compiler magic in Oxygene is the **typeof()** built-in function:

```
cname := new ComponentName( self, typeof(SomeClass) );
```